# disable dropdown option value in iPhone?

Tags: html, iphone, drop-down-menu, html-select

how to disable the `<option>` in `select` menu? I can handle this situation in browser but I cant in iPhone.  Except approved option I disabled all. Here I attached the screenshot. Can any one tell me how fix this? thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in Safari for iOS. You can do 2 things:

- Remove the options you don't want to be visible from the list
- Tell the user that he made an invalid selection when he tries to commit the form

No other options here...

Answer (score 0):

There are some standard options, if you try then this type of issue will resolved.
Try to use group options this will work with all devices and web browsers.
Tested with Android and iPhone4 and iPhone4s

```
<optgroup label='field name 1'>
   <option value='1'>Name 1</option>
   <option value='2'>Name 2</option>
   <option value='3'>Name 3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label='field name 2'>
   <option value='1'>Name 1</option>
   <option value='2'>Name 2</option>
   <option value='3'>Name 3</option>
</optgroup>
```